# why do i get an error -[__NSArrayM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd4d15211d0 while assigning data to custom tableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsarray, nsmutabledictionary

```
NSMutableDictionary *persondict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[persondict setObject:fullName forKey:@"givenName"];
[persondict setObject:identity forKey:@"identifier"];
[persondict setObject:_mobnumberarray forKey:@"CNLabelPhoneNumberMobile"];
[persondict setObject:_iphoneArray forKey:@"CNLabelPhoneNumberiPhone"];
[_Contacts addObject:persondict];
```

Here above is my dictionary populated with two arrays, but when I       try to display the _Contacts array on tableview it gives me following     error on the console screen:

> [__NSArrayM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x7fd4d15211d0

**Here is my table view method:**

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:  (NSInteger)section
{
    return _Contacts.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView    cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"tableViewCell";
    tableViewCell * cell = [tableView      dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.celll.text = [[_Contacts  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"givenName"];
    cell.idcell.text=[[_Contacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"identifier"];
    cell.numbercell.text=[[_Contacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"CNLabelPhoneNumberMobile"];
    cell.iphonecell.text=[[_Contacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"CNLabelPhoneNumberiPhone"];
    return cell;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you use `valueForKey:`? And if there is various numbers, what do you do? Try to use `[[[_Contacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"CNLabelPhoneNumberMobile"] firstObject]` instead?

Comment: thanks a lot for the suggestion. it did worked for me.

Comment: but its displaying the same numbers throughout the list view row

Comment: please help me..it just displays the first object of the array

Comment: `[[[_Contacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"CNLabelPhoneNumberMobile"] componentsSeparatedByString:@", "]`? It hard to know what you really want to do.

Comment: sir i am trying to fetch the contacts using cncontact store and display them on a table view...but as the numbers are labeled values, i am not able to display them on the tableView. this is my problem...rest name and contact id i am able to display them.

Comment: as contact numbers are having labels like home, office, work, etc..

Comment: and i tried your above method but it is showing warning like  incompatible pointer types assigning nsstring _nullable to nsarray<nsstring> _nullable

Answer (score 3):

If _Contact is of type NSMutableArray then try this, else replace the type:

`_Contact = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`